# Why don't Cardview rounded corners work in a Google Maps Infowindow on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

My Android app has a custom InfoWindow layout for Google Maps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?attr/fullscreenBackgroundColor"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.FullscreenContainer">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center|center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The layout looks fine in Android Studio of course, because it's a disembodied layout view. But on actual Android devices (I've tried three) this layout applies to the Google Maps Infowindow, and it's not showing rounded corners.

What am I missing? Or is this not going to work because there's something special about the GoogleMaps infoWindow? Perhaps there are separate setting for the InfoWindow itself that can create rounded corners but I wasn't able to find them.

So...how do I make the Google Maps infowindows() have rounded corners?

Comment: Have you tried adding padding (via `android:padding`) or margins to the `CardView`?

Comment: There is zero relation to Kotlin, as the `InforWindowAdapter` is absent... there's also `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`... while actually, just dumping the GUI and/or displaying layout boundaries  should make it obvious why it doesn't display as expected.

Comment: I have no idea about infoViews but GoogleMaps itself (I'm talking about the Maps SDK view which shows a map in your app) uses a GLSurfaceView which renders the on native code (using OpenGL in cpp) and does not use normal texture surface (CardView uses path clipping on Canvas which is a part of that) it enables Maps SDK to render faster and more smoothly using hardware layer (instead of software layers(texture,canvas,etc)) I suspect the situation you're describing is something related to this as well, and simple answer is that you cannot do that easily with a Canvas AKA CardView clipping

Comment: I personally needed that (But on MapBox SDK) and MapBox has the capability to be rendered on both GLSurface and Texture. So I've switched it to TextureMode. I don't know if Google Maps also provides this flexibility (but I'm curious to know)

Comment: I've tried padding & margins. No difference.
ShapeableImageView seems to work but it has other issues, the main one being it doesn't honor the background/color of any of the layers below it.